# How to redirect to another view with parameter in this example?

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have an intro.html *rendering* view here:

```
def home(request):
    user = request.user
    small = user.username.title()
    cases = Case.objects.filter(users=user).order_by('-english')
    groups = user.groups.all()
    allgroups = Group.objects.all()
    suggestgroups = set(allgroups).difference(set(groups))
    allusers = User.objects.all().exclude(username=user.username)

    if not user.is_superuser:
        user_ex = UserEx.objects.get(user=request.user)
        friendlist = FriendList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
        friends = friendlist.friends.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        friendrequest = FriendReqRecList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
        friendrequestsent = FriendReqSentList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
        friendrequests = friendrequest.friend_rec_requests.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        friendrequestsents = friendrequestsent.friend_sent_requests.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        nonfriends = set(allusers).difference(set(friends))
        return render(request, 'intro.html',
                      {'allusers': allusers,
                       'cases': cases,
                       'friendrequests': friendrequests,
                       'friendrequestsents': friendrequestsents,
                       'friends': friends,
                       'groups': groups,
                       'nonfriends': nonfriends,
                       'small' : small,
                       'suggestgroups': suggestgroups})
    return render(request, 'intro.html', {'suggestgroups': suggestgroups,
                                          'cases': cases,
                                          'groups': groups,
                                          'small' : small})
```

I have another share view which adds friends and groups to the intro.html (the change is only extra two parameters, sendfriends and sendgroups).

```
@login_required
def share(request):
    user = request.user
    small = user.username.title()
    cases = Case.objects.filter(users=user).order_by('-english')
    groups = user.groups.all()
    allgroups = Group.objects.all()
    suggestgroups = set(allgroups).difference(set(groups))
    allusers = User.objects.all().exclude(username=user.username)

    sendgroups = groups

    if not user.is_superuser:
        user_ex = UserEx.objects.get(user=request.user)
        friendlist = FriendList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
        friends = friendlist.friends.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        friendrequest = FriendReqRecList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
        friendrequestsent = FriendReqSentList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
        friendrequests = friendrequest.friend_rec_requests.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        friendrequestsents = friendrequestsent.friend_sent_requests.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        nonfriends = set(allusers).difference(set(friends))

        sendfriends = friendlist.friends.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        return render(request, 'intro.html',
                      {'sendfriends': sendfriends,
                       'sendgroups': sendgroups,
                       'allusers': allusers,
                       'cases': cases,
                       'friendrequests': friendrequests,
                       'friendrequestsents': friendrequestsents,
                       'friends': friends,
                       'groups': groups,
                       'nonfriends': nonfriends,
                       'small' : small,
                       'suggestgroups': suggestgroups})

    return render(request, 'intro.html', {'suggestgroups': suggestgroups,
                                          'cases': cases,
                                          'groups': groups,
                                          'small' : small})
```

The second view also renders intro.html with extra two parameters (sendfriends and sendgroups). But I want to obey the don't repeat yourself **(DRY)** rule and use *redirect()* here. How can I pass these two parameters and redirect to home view over share view?

Comment: is the code in the two functions identical?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is the two additional parameters in the second one.

Comment: If you look at your question closely. They have the exact same parameters :-)

Comment: sendgroups and sendfriends are new :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
def home(request):
    return render_intro(request)


@login_required
def share(request):
    return render_intro(request, is_share=True)


def render_intro(request, is_share=False):
    context = intro_context(request.user, is_share)
    return render(request, 'intro.html', context)


def intro_context(user, is_share=False):
    small = user.username.title()
    cases = Case.objects.filter(users=user).order_by('-english')
    groups = user.groups.all()
    allgroups = Group.objects.all()
    suggestgroups = set(allgroups).difference(set(groups))
    allusers = User.objects.all().exclude(username=user.username)

    if user.is_superuser:
        return {'suggestgroups': suggestgroups,
                'cases': cases,
                'groups': groups,
                'small' : small}

    user_ex = UserEx.objects.get(user=user)
    friendlist = FriendList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
    friends = friendlist.friends.all().exclude(username=user.username)
    friendrequest = FriendReqRecList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
    friendrequestsent = FriendReqSentList.objects.get(user=user_ex)
    friendrequests = friendrequest.friend_rec_requests.all().exclude(username=user.username)
    friendrequestsents = friendrequestsent.friend_sent_requests.all().exclude(username=user.username)
    nonfriends = set(allusers).difference(set(friends))

    context = {'allusers': allusers,
               'cases': cases,
               'friendrequests': friendrequests,
               'friendrequestsents': friendrequestsents,
               'friends': friends,
               'groups': groups,
               'nonfriends': nonfriends,
               'small' : small,
               'suggestgroups': suggestgroups}

    if is_share:
        sendgroups = groups
        sendfriends = friendlist.friends.all().exclude(username=user.username)
        context.update({'sendfriends': sendfriends,
                        'sendgroups': sendgroups})

    return context
```

Comment: It obeys the DRY rule, but can't we simply handle it with django's redirect() method?

Comment: like: redirect('handler:home', sendgroups = sendgroups, sendfriends = sendfriends)

Comment: It doesn't look like a job for redirect. And this answer looks ok. The real trouble is with all the queries you are running.  Might I suggest you post another question with your models and queries and ask if there is a way to simplify it.

Comment: The `redirect` is for redirecting to another page, i.e the client will receive a HTTP Status 302 and go to the redirected view you inform. In your case you are incrementing the context and returning the same view always, the `intro`.

Comment: Actually I am medical student currently got interest in programming which means I am a newbie :-). Is having this many queries a bad practice; does it slow down the server?

Comment: Not a bad practice as you need all the information. May be some optimization is going to be made if necessary, but before that I would like to quote this _"Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- [Donald Knuth](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)_.

Comment: Oh, I am happy to hear that. Thank you for the suggestions. I will give a try.